# Applying Recursion for Subset Sum

Tags: java, subset

I'm trying to make a code that adds all the integers in a subset to see if they add up to zero. Here's what I've got so far

```
  /**
   * Solve the subset sum problem for a set of integer values.
   * 
   * @param t
   *          a set of integer values
   * @return <code>true</code> if there exists a non-empty subset of
   *         <code>t</code> whose elements sum to zero.
   */
  public static boolean subsetSum(Set<Integer> t) {
    return subsetSum(new ArrayList<Integer>(t), null);
  }

  /**
   * Computes the sum of two Integers where one or both references are null. If
   * both references are null then the result is null; otherwise the result is
   * an integer equal to <code>a + b</code> where null references are treated as
   * being equal to zero.
   * 
   * @param a
   * @param b
   * @return the sum of <code>a</code> and <code>b</code>
   */
  private static Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if (a == null && b == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (a == null) {
      return b;
    } else if (b == null) {
      return a;
    }
    return a + b;
  }

  /**
   * Recursive solution for the subset sum problem.
   * 
   * <p>
   * <code>currentSum</code> holds the value of the subset under consideration;
   * it should be <code>null</code> if the current subset is empty.
   * 
   * @param t
   *          a list containing unique integer values (a set of integers)
   * @param currentSum
   *          the current subset sum so far
   * @return <code>true</code> if there exists a subset of <code>t</code> such
   *         that the sum of the elements in the subset and
   *         <code>currentSum</code> equals zero.
   */

******** THIS IS THE PART I HAD TO EDIT *************
  private static boolean subsetSum(List<Integer> t, Integer currentSum) {
      currentSum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < t.size(); i++) {
          currentSum = currentSum + (Integer)(t.get(i));
      }
      if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(0)) == 0) {
          return true;
      }
      else if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(1)) == 0) {
          return true;
      } else if (Lab9W.add(-t.get(0),t.get(0)) == 0) {
          return true;
      }
      else {
          return false;
      }

  }

}
```

here what tip I have received about making this code :

> consider the first element of the set first is there a subset sum of
>   zero with first and the rest of the set? is there a subset sum of zero
>   without first and the rest of the set? if either of 2 or 3 is true
>   then return true, otherwise return false

Any help please I've been trying all day i can not get it to work for the life of me, well in recursion i cant figure out how to call the method on itself.

So my question is how would I write this method in recursion? The whole method is supposed to add the sum of subsets and see if they equal to zero.

Comment: your trying to check is the first element in the array + the sum of all the elements is equal to 0?

Comment: yes i am @JavaNewb cause thats what was suggested no?

Comment: your whole logic simply does not make sense. I doubt if you actually understand what the problem is.  Assume you have 5 integer in the set : a,b,c,d,e .  you should return true if any of these integer sum up to 0.  e.g. if a + b +d == 0 then return true.  Your logic simply did nothing related.  You are simply adding up the whole list, and if the total sum + value of first/second element (again!) == 0, or first element is not null, then you return true.  What's the point of this logic?

Comment: Well I'm not sure that's why I'm confused I don't understand I'm very confused :( @adrianshum

Comment: ok so your just trying to check if the sum of the elements is equal to 0? using recursion?

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do it :( I've asked a couple of friends and none understand it @JavaNewb

Comment: ok your if statement is just... if(sum == 0)return true; else return false;

Comment: Wait is that what its supposed to be or what its now :(

Comment: @callmealb obviously the question is not asking "sum of elements of list equals to zero".  It explicitly mentioned about subset.  And, it is really irresponsible for you just to throw the homework here, and you can't even explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Dude I've been trying I tried to explain it but I'm really tired I've been trying to get it all day but no progress I'm sorry if you're offended I just wanted to understand how to do it I'm new to programming and I'm not as fast picking it up ... I'm very greatful to @JavaNewb for helping don't get me wrong and I'm sorry if I asked wrongly

Comment: its all good, i understand what the other guy is saying.

Answer (score 0):

ok you can do something like this for recursion

```
 private static boolean subsetSum(List<Integer> t, Integer sizeOfArray,Integer currentSum){

      if(sizeOfArray == -1)
      {
        if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(0)) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(1)) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (Lab9W.add(-t.get(0),t.get(0)) == 0) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

       return subsetSum(t,sizeOfArray - 1,currentSum + t.get(sizeOfArray));
 }
```

i typed it with out checking but thats sort of the consept. play arroud with this idea

the first call should be like this

```
subsetSum(array,array.size()-1,0); // i dont know if its array.size()-1 // it is...
```

//
ok you can also do this...

```
    // return sum of array
    public Integer subsetSum(List<Integer> t, Integer sizeOfArray) 
    {
        if(sizeOfArray == 0)
            return t.get(0);
        return subsetSum(t, sizeOfArray - 1) + t.get(sizeOfArray);
    }
```

//now you can do this somewere

```
     public boolean check(List<Integer> t)
{
        Integer currentSum = subsetSum(t,t.size()-1); 

        if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(0)) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(1)) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Lab9W.add(-t.get(0),t.get(0)) == 0) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
}
```

Comment: yeah but when i applied your modified code, it gives me an error: must return type of boolean :/ @JavaNewb also the private static boolean subsetSum(List<Integer> t, Integer currentSum)  has to be the same i dont think i can edit this

Comment: right i didnt test it, but i just edited it abit, i added a return

Comment: you cant add a new argument?

Comment: No I don't think so :( @javanewb

Comment: I can do it if i can return an Integer is that ok?so i return the current sum then check the if statements, is this ok?

Comment: Give me what you can bro :) as long as it works :p if not u can return with system.out BTW thanks a lot its been bothering me all day I was starting to go crazy! @JavaNewb

Comment: ok i added a new one, i think this is what you teacher wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
// return sum of array
    public Integer subsetSum(List<Integer> t, Integer sizeOfArray) 
    {
        if(sizeOfArray == 0)
            return t.get(0);
        return subsetSum(t, sizeOfArray - 1) + t.get(sizeOfArray);
    }
//now you can do this somewere

     public boolean check(List<Integer> t)
{
        Integer currentSum = subsetSum(t,t.size()-1); 

        if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(0)) == 0) // do something with these if statements
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Lab9W.add(currentSum, t.get(1)) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (Lab9W.add(-t.get(0),t.get(0)) == 0) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it similar to this question? And how you can solve it?

Given a set of whole weight stones, can divide them into 2 groups with weight
Exactly equal.
Write a recursive function

public static boolean canSplit (int [] stones, int left, int right)

Which, given a set of weights stones mean function can be divided into two groups) left
And right- (so that the whole team is worth. Use the function subArray if necessary.
Training: Look at the first stone and recursive decided which group has associated with it.